# Table entry shifted downwards with Hyperref package

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, hyperref

I wanted to make a table with two columns: the left column lists the terms that the right column explains. Also I'd like to make the terms on the left column **link to itself**. The minimum working example below shows what I wanted and also the problem I have.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen,pdffitwindow]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfview=FitB,pdfpagetransition=Dissolve}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\pagebreak

\section{Definitions}
The following terms are used in one or more books of these specifications.

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.2\linewidth}X}
\hypertarget{AR}{}\hyperlink{AR}{Accelerated Revocation} & A key revocation performed on a date sooner than the published key expiry date.\
\hypertarget{App}{}\hyperlink{App}{Application} & The application protocol between the card and the terminal and its related set of data.\
\hypertarget{AAC}{}\hyperlink{AAC}{Application Authentication Cryptogram} & An Application Cryptogram generated by the card when declining a transaction.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen, the left column entries are all shifted down. I feel that adding a vertical distance manually is not a correct way to solve it. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Answer (score 4):

`\hypertarget` doesn't start a paragraph by itself, but still it establishes the reference point for the box because it inserts a “whatsit”. There are good reasons for not starting a paragraph, since `\hypertarget` can well be used for pointing to some position in the page such as immediately before a title.

The whatsit is a technical feature that can't be removed.

Solution: add `\leavevmode` before `\hypertarget`.

Still I don't understand why creating a link pointing just to the same place.

---

What happens is similar to this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

X\parbox[t]{1cm}{\vspace{0pt}Y}

\end{document}
```

A `p{<dimen>}` column is just like `\parbox[t]{<dimen>}`. In the example, `\vspace{0pt}` doesn't produce output, but establishes the reference point for the top of the box, which is the baseline of the first item in it. A whatsit acts similarly to `\vspace{0pt}`, so the visible effect is that the *printed* first item appears to be shifted down.

It's *not* shifted down, actually: it's the box's reference point that's higher than what you expected.

Comment: I don't see the connection of "not starting a paragraph" and text being shifted down. \hypertarget inserts something vertically and \leavevmode removes that?

Comment: @Rich I added some explanation for the phenomenon. I still can't understand why you want something to link to itself: it's disorienting.

Comment: I wanted all occurrences of the terms throughout the document to be links so that they appear consistent. I probably should reconsider this approach...

Comment: If \vspace{0pt} causes the reference point for the top of the  parbox to be higher, shouldn't the following text be typeset higher too, assuming the following text's reference points align with that of the top of the parbox...

Comment: @Rich I don't understand. The reference point of the box is at the baseline of the surrounding text: TeX vertically aligns boxes in a line with their reference points on the baseline.